# Which is the best way to built a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

1. Should I make a static website using xhtml, css and javascript first and then convert it to a wordpress theme.
   OR
2. Should I directly start building the theme from scratch.
   OR
3. Should I use any framework
   OR
4. Combination of the above.

Comment: 3 you don't need it. You can use 1 or 2 or combination of both and it is highly depends on the design. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend 3, starting from a an existing theme. It's easier to strip away (or ignore) than to have to implement from scratch (or forget to implement which may hit you later on). The trick is to start from a theme that is close to what you need without too much bagage.

I would also chose a barebone theme based on HTML5 with shivs to support older browsers. HTML5Boilerplate.com is probably the most contributed HTML5 template project. It is a solid starting point and many Wordpress themes are based on it. Google HTML5 boilerplate wordpress and maybe barebone and you'll find quite a few templates. Here's one https://github.com/zencoder/html5-boilerplate-for-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

I always use the first method, but it may not be the best for you.
Once you have built a few you'll most likely have a code base to simply insert into your html/css.

You could also get a pre-made theme with a layout like what your new design has, and modify that. Its a great way to learn how themes are made

Comment: Or you can just get the tags and loop etc from the wordpress website